# Настройка сервера VPN xl2tp без IPSec

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, l2tp, xl2tp

Подскажите, с чего начать, в какую сторону копать? Нужно установить VPN сервер на ubuntu server 20.04 по устаревшей технологии L2TP без IPSec. Это можно сделать с помощью xl2tp. Авторизация должна быть по логину и паролю на старом роутере. Пока что понял только как установить:
sudo apt install xl2tpd
А дальше что?
Я даже банально инструкцию почему-то не могу найти на в гугле, ни в яндексе. А чатГПТ галлюцинирует и выдумывает что-то. Даже банально ссылке буду рад на статью об этом.

Comment: L2TP устарела ?

Comment: Разве не устарела? Сейчас все OpenVPN ставят и WireGuard.

Answer (score 1):

L2TP это метод инкапсуляции PPP, соответственно почти всё настраивать нужно в конфигурационных файлах демона pppd, обычно это `/etc/ppp`.

В репозитории xl2tpd есть [примеры](https://github.com/xelerance/xl2tpd/tree/master/examples) конфигурационных файлов для типовых VPN.

Самая простая конфигурация:

#### /etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf

```
[global]
access control = no

[lns default]
exclusive = yes
ip range = 192.168.251.201-192.168.251.210
local ip = 192.168.251.200
length bit = yes
flow bit = yes
require authentication = yes
name = xl2tpd
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
```

#### /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd

```
auth
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
mtu 1460
mru 1460
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
debug
```

#### /etc/ppp/chap-secrets

```
usernamehere        xl2tpd  passwordhere        *
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно настроить через [accel-ppp](https://accel-ppp.org/). Это такой VPN сервер уровня провайдера. [Готовая сборка для Ubuntu20 по ссылке](https://disk.yandex.com/d/-WnIlzoenvn9Gg) или самостоятельно

```
apt install cmake build-essentials libnl-3-dev libssl-dev libpcre32-3
git clone https://github.com/accel-ppp/accel-ppp.git
mkdir accel-ppp-build
cd accel-ppp-build/
cmake ../accel-ppp -DRADIUS=FALSE -DNETSNMP=TRUE -DSHAPER=TRUE  -DCPACK_TYPE=Ubuntu20 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
cpack -G DEB
dpkg -i accel-ppp.deb
```

Пример для настройки `l2tp`+`pptp`+`sstp` сервера с пользователями в `chap-secrets`. Скрипты для ppp-compat

```
mkdir -p /etc/ppp/
touch /etc/ppp/ip-up
touch /etc/ppp/ip-down
touch /etc/ppp/ip-change
touch /etc/ppp/ip-pre-up
touch /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
chmod +x /etc/ppp/ip-*
```

#### /etc/accel-ppp.conf

```
[modules]
#log_file
log_syslog
#log_tcp
#log_pgsql

pptp
l2tp
sstp
#pppoe
#ipoe

auth_mschap_v2
auth_mschap_v1
auth_chap_md5
auth_pap

#radius
chap-secrets

#ippool

pppd_compat

#shaper
#net-snmp
#logwtmp
#connlimit

#ipv6_nd
#ipv6_dhcp
#ipv6pool

[core]
log-error=/var/log/accel-ppp/core.log
thread-count=4

[common]
#single-session=replace
#sid-case=upper
#sid-source=seq
#max-sessions=1000

[ppp]
verbose=1
min-mtu=1280
mtu=1400
mru=1400
#accomp=deny
#pcomp=deny
#ccp=0
#check-ip=0
#mppe=require
ipv4=require
ipv6=deny
ipv6-intf-id=0:0:0:1
ipv6-peer-intf-id=0:0:0:2
ipv6-accept-peer-intf-id=1
lcp-echo-interval=20
lcp-echo-failure=5
lcp-echo-timeout=120
unit-cache=1
#unit-preallocate=1

[auth]
#any-login=0
#noauth=0

[pptp]
verbose=1
echo-interval=30
ifname=pptp-%d

[pppoe]
verbose=1
#ac-name=xxx
#service-name=yyy
#pado-delay=0
#pado-delay=0,100:100,200:200,-1:500
called-sid=mac
#tr101=1
#padi-limit=0
#ip-pool=pppoe
#ifname=pppoe%d
#sid-uppercase=0
#vlan-mon=eth0,10-200
#vlan-timeout=60
#vlan-name=%I.%N
#interface=eth1,padi-limit=1000
#interface=eth0

[l2tp]
#verbose=1
#dictionary=/usr/local/share/accel-ppp/l2tp/dictionary
#hello-interval=60
timeout=60
#rtimeout=1
#rtimeout-cap=16
#retransmit=5
#recv-window=16
#host-name=accel-ppp
dir300_quirk=1
#secret=
dataseq=allow
#reorder-timeout=0
#ip-pool=l2tp
ifname=l2tp-%d

[sstp]
verbose=1
#cert-hash-proto=sha1,sha256
#cert-hash-sha1=
#cert-hash-sha256=
accept=ssl,proxy
#ssl-dhparam=/etc/ssl/dhparam.pem
#ssl-ecdh-curve=prime256v1
#ssl-ciphers=DEFAULT
#ssl-prefer-server-ciphers=0
ssl-ca-file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/%%%YOURHOSTHERE%%%/chain.pem
ssl-pemfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/%%%YOURHOSTHERE%%%/cert.pem
ssl-keyfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/%%%YOURHOSTHERE%%%/privkey.pem
host-name=%%%YOURHOSTHERE%%%
http-error=allow
#timeout=60
#hello-interval=60
#ip-pool=sstp
ifname=sstp-%d
port=443

[ipoe]
verbose=1
username=ifname
#password=username
lease-time=600
renew-time=300
max-lease-time=3600
#unit-cache=1000
#l4-redirect-table=4
#l4-redirect-ipset=l4
#l4-redirect-on-reject=300
#l4-redirect-ip-pool=pool1
shared=0
ifcfg=1
mode=L2
start=dhcpv4
#start=UP
#ip-unnumbered=1
#proxy-arp=0
#nat=0
#proto=100
#relay=10.10.10.10
#vendor=Custom
#weight=0
#attr-dhcp-client-ip=DHCP-Client-IP-Address
#attr-dhcp-router-ip=DHCP-Router-IP-Address
#attr-dhcp-mask=DHCP-Mask
#attr-dhcp-lease-time=DHCP-Lease-Time
#attr-dhcp-opt82=DHCP-Option82
#attr-dhcp-opt82-remote-id=DHCP-Agent-Remote-Id
#attr-dhcp-opt82-circuit-id=DHCP-Agent-Circuit-Id
#attr-l4-redirect=L4-Redirect
#attr-l4-redirect-table=4
#attr-l4-redirect-ipset=l4-redirect
#lua-file=/etc/accel-ppp.lua
#offer-delay=0,100:100,200:200,-1:1000
#vlan-mon=eth0,10-200
#vlan-timeout=60
#vlan-name=%I.%N
#ip-pool=ipoe
#idle-timeout=0
#session-timeout=0
#soft-terminate=0
#check-mac-change=1
#calling-sid=mac
#local-net=192.168.0.0/16
interface=eth0


[dns]
#dns1=172.16.0.1
#dns2=172.16.1.1

[wins]
#wins1=172.16.0.1
#wins2=172.16.1.1

[radius]
#dictionary=/usr/local/share/accel-ppp/radius/dictionary
nas-identifier=accel-ppp
nas-ip-address=127.0.0.1
gw-ip-address=192.168.100.1
server=127.0.0.1,testing123,auth-port=1812,acct-port=1813,req-limit=50,fail-timeout=0,max-fail=10,weight=1
dae-server=127.0.0.1:3799,testing123
verbose=1
#timeout=3
#max-try=3
#acct-timeout=120
#acct-delay-time=0
#acct-on=0
#attr-tunnel-type=My-Tunnel-Type

[client-ip-range]
0.0.0.0/0

[ip-pool]
gw-ip-address=192.168.94.1
#vendor=Cisco
#attr=Cisco-AVPair
attr=Framed-Pool
192.168.94.2-255

[log]
#log-file=/var/log/accel-ppp/accel-ppp.log
#log-emerg=/var/log/accel-ppp/emerg.log
#log-fail-file=/var/log/accel-ppp/auth-fail.log
#log-debug=/dev/stdout
syslog=accel-pppd,daemon
#log-tcp=127.0.0.1:3000
#copy=1
#color=1
#per-user-dir=per_user
#per-session-dir=per_session
#per-session=1
level=3

[log-pgsql]
conninfo=user=log
log-table=log

[pppd-compat]
verbose=1
#ip-pre-up=/etc/ppp/ip-pre-up
ip-up=/etc/ppp/ip-up
ip-down=/etc/ppp/ip-down
#ip-change=/etc/ppp/ip-change
radattr-prefix=/var/run/radattr
#fork-limit=16

[chap-secrets]
gw-ip-address=192.168.94.1
chap-secrets=/etc/ppp/chap-secrets
#encrypted=0
#username-hash=md5

[shaper]
#attr=Filter-Id
#down-burst-factor=0.1
#up-burst-factor=1.0
#latency=50
#mpu=0
#mtu=0
#r2q=10
#quantum=1500
#moderate-quantum=1
#cburst=1534
#ifb=ifb0
up-limiter=police
down-limiter=tbf
#leaf-qdisc=sfq perturb 10
#leaf-qdisc=fq_codel [limit PACKETS] [flows NUMBER] [target TIME] [interval TIME] [quantum BYTES] [[no]ecn]
#rate-multiplier=1
#fwmark=1
verbose=1

[cli]
verbose=1
telnet=127.0.0.1:2000
tcp=127.0.0.1:2001
#password=123
#sessions-columns=ifname,username,ip,ip6,ip6-dp,type,state,uptime,uptime-raw,calling-sid,called-sid,sid,comp,rx-bytes,tx-bytes,rx-bytes-raw,tx-bytes-raw,rx-pkts,tx-pkts

[snmp]
master=0
agent-name=accel-ppp

[connlimit]
limit=10/min
burst=3
timeout=60

[ipv6-pool]
#gw-ip6-address=fc00:0:1::1
fc00:0:1::/48,64
delegate=fc00:1::/36,48

[ipv6-dns]
#fc00:1::1
#fc00:1::2
#fc00:1::3
#dnssl=suffix1.local.net
#dnssl=suffix2.local.net.

[ipv6-dhcp]
verbose=1
pref-lifetime=604800
valid-lifetime=2592000
route-via-gw=1
```

Получи сертификат для домена и укажи путь в конфиге выше. Или отключи sstp закомментировав строчку sstp.

Пользователей заводишь через

#### /etc/ppp/chap-secrets

```
username  * password 192.168.94.2
```